# Problem with GCP project relying on GDELT database

Tags: google-bigquery

While programming in GCP using the "GDELT" database I encountered a problem, and would like for you to help me solve it.

I would like to program a code in which the database will examine who the person the media dealt with the most during the days of signing the "Abraham Accords" between Israel and the Arab countries.

```
SELECT
  V2Persons,
  COUNT(1) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT
    UNIQUE(REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(V2Persons,';'), r',.*', ")) V2Persons
      FROM
        `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
      WHERE
        DATE>20200914000000
        AND DATE < 20200916000000
        AND LOWER(AllNames) LIKE '%Abraham Accords%' )
    GROUP BY
      Persons
    ORDER BY
      2 DESC
    LIMIT
      300
```

Can you show me what the problem is with the code and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues here, simplest to debug step-by-step, using `WITH` statement and getting some data.

So I moved nested query to WITH sub-query. There is no UNIQUE function, I've removed it. Then the `SPLIT` function returns an array, you cannot just call REGEX function on array, the array first has to be `UNNEST`'ed. I got this in the end:

```sql
WITH persons AS (
    SELECT SPLIT(gkg.V2Persons,';') pers_arr
      FROM
        `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned` gkg
      WHERE
        DATE > 20200914000000 AND DATE < 20200916000000 AND
        LOWER(AllNames) LIKE '%abraham accord%'
)    
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(V2Persons, r',.*', '') V2Persons, COUNT(1) AS count 
FROM persons pers, UNNEST(pers.pers_arr) V2Persons
GROUP BY V2Persons
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 300;
```